# aws cdk apigateway MethodResponse not found

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-cdk

I am trying to access the MethodResponse interface from apigateway but I am getting an error in vscode.

Property 'MethodResponse' does not exist on type 'typeof import(".../node_modules/aws-cdk-lib/aws-apigateway/index")'

Here is my import

```
import { aws_apigateway as apigateway } from 'aws-cdk-lib'
```

here is where I am attempting to access MethodResponse

```
inputMethod.addMethodResponse(
   apigateway.MethodResponse = {
      statusCode: '200',
      responseModels: {
         responseModelsKey: inputModel
      }
   }
)
```

I checked the node_modules/aws-apigateway/lib folder and the index.d.ts does contain the export line

```
export * from './methodresponse';
```

and the methodresponse.d.ts also exists. I deleted the node_modules and reinstalled everything and I am still getting the same error. Has anyone encountered this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the API reference for the [aws_apigateway module](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_apigateway-readme.html).

I prefer to import every member individually. For example, here is the import statement for the `MethodResponse` structure.

```js
import { MethodResponse } from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-apigateway'
```

The module name is `aws_apigateway` but you import from `aws-cdk-lib/aws-apigateway`.

The code you provided does not look like a valid TypeScript code. I guess you wanted to specify type for the `addMethodResponse` parameter like the following.

```js
inputMethod.addMethodResponse({
  statusCode: '200',
  responseModels: {
    responseModelsKey: inputModel
  }
} as MethodResponse)
```

Though we do not need this and can omit the `as MethodResponse` part.